# Unexpected behavoiur of define of requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, require

This code is working

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone,home_template) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({    
        render: function() {  
            alert('abcd');
        }
    });

    return HomeView;  
});
```

this code is not working

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!modules/home/home_template.html'
], 
function($, _, Backbone,home_template) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({    
        render: function() {  
            alert('abcd');
        }
    });  
    return HomeView;  
});
```

My directory structure is like  **webroot/modules/home/home_template.html**

What can be the problem ??

Thanks

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: @Evgeniy thanks for commment. I got this error "Error: Script error for: text http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror"

Comment: could u please attach src of home_template.html ?

Comment: @Evgeniy - after your comment I changed my home_template.html content to      **<div>abcd</div>**     . I checked it again, but result was as before.

I think I have problem in    **require.config({paths:{}});**   

What do you think??

Comment: there are to possible issues 1) error in path(u can check in in fireBug or any other tool in network tab, look for 404 errors) 2) error in template syntax - in case of underscore be sure your template wrapped in <script type="template">

Comment: @Evgeniy - Thanks for the solution. Finally I could solve the problem with the help of you. I used network tab as per your instruction. I found that a file named **text.js** not loaded.I collected the file and put it in a right place and the problem solved. **Thanks**

Comment: glad to help, i'll post my comment as answer, if i found it usefull may mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be in two possible places:

1) Error in path(u can check in in fireBug or any other tool in network tab, look for 404 errors). It might be template or some other scripts  placed inn wrong folder.

2) Error in template syntax - in case of underscore be sure your template wrapped in `<script type="template">`.